# Can Application Insights send a notification when an Azure Function executes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured to monitor an Azure Function and have setup an alert to notify me (via email) if the function fails.  I actually would like to receive a notification every time the function runs(once per week). I feel that this should be easy to do but I'm new to Application Insights and not sure if I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: Yes it is possible, send a event to app insights and create an alert from app insights everytime your receive this type of event

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions integration with Application Insights will create a metric for each Function which tracks count and duration (avg). You can create an Alert based on that metric for count and alert anytime it is greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: I tried @chris solution and it did fire an email the first time the function ran but didn't send subsequent notifications.

Comment: It's generally done in a time window, so it won't send an email for each execution, but for a certain time window.

If you want an email for **each** execution, have it call a Logic App after it runs, and have the Logic App send you an email. That's more business logic than monitoring, at that point.